# Android ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT is it possible to prefill filename?

Tags: java, android

In android app I want to export some data to a file. I use Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT which lets user choose where to save it. Is it possible to prefill the filename, e.g. "data.txt"? If I use intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "data.txt") it is simply ignored.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "data.txt"); // this is ignored
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_CREATE_DOCUMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I don't want to make custom dialog because using ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT allows me to write file to storage without any permissions (because user is choosing file).

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/content/Intent#action_create_document), `EXTRA_TITLE` is the right answer. What device(s) have you tested on?

Comment: Android 5.1, and Android 10, both empty (filename is not pre-filled)